# Java - Is a copy of a static variable also static?

Tags: java, static, hashmap

I have a static Hashmap, A. I am making a copy of it, B, for calculations. When I delete elements from B and print A, those elements are gone from A too. Is this expected?

```
    Static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> A;

    private void calculate(String id) {

    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> B= A;
    String maxKey = getMaxKey(B);

    int neighbour_matrix_length = B.size();

    for(int i=0 ; i< neighbour_matrix_length; i++){ 

    // remove all the visited nodes 
    ArrayList<String> visited = copy_neighbours_reachability_map.get(maxKey);

    for(int j = 0; j< visited.size() ; j++)
    {
    String temp = visited.get(i);
    Iterator<Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> iter = B.entrySet().iterator();
    // iterate through the hashmap to remove elements
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry = iter.next();
        if(entry.getValue().contains(temp)){
        entry.getValue().remove(temp);
        }
    }
    }
    }
   // Elements from A are also getting deleted..
   System.out.println("neighbours_reachability_map is ");
   for (String key : A.keySet())
   {
    System.out.println( "Key : " + key + " - " + A.get(key).toString());
   }
   }
```

Am I missing something? I do not want elements from A to be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is only sharing reference to the same object, so changing one will change another. Doing this:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> B = new HashMap<>(A);
```

will make a copy of the map, but... Values in your map are lists and both maps will keep references to the same lists (even if new and old map are different objects). So you need to copy lists as well:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> B = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> e : A.entrySet()) {
    B.put(e.getKey(), new ArrayList<String>(e.getValue()));
}
```

What we're doing here is creating **deep copy** of the object, so none of the references are shared.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot @xersiee.  Small typo in your comments - ---- for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> e : A.entrySet())

Answer (score 3):

> I am making a copy of it, B, for calculations. When I delete elements from B and print A, those elements are gone from A too. Is this expected?

Yes the behavior you observe is expected, because when you say `Map<String, ArrayList<String>> B= A;`, then `B` refers to the **same** `Map` as `A` (that is, `B == A`, which means they share the same reference). You could **copy** `A` to `B` with something like

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> B = new HashMap<>(A);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Elliot. But for some reason, even after implementing what you suggested, elements from A are also getting deleted. =(